# Short function which i don't understand?

Tags: javascript, function, max, prompt, console.log

I'm studying in the 1st year at a university in Italy. We started studying js on different online courses...
I have to do an exercise in a few days, and I know, it's very simple.
I have a function " max (a,b) " and I have to print out which is the biggest number, if A or B.
I created a function, and I don't know how to give them a value in input from my keyboard, and I also don't know how to print out a string like : "the biggest number is (return A) or (b).

```
    function max(a,b) {

   a = Number(prompt("INSERISCI IL PRIMO NUMERO: "));
   b = Number(prompt("INSERISCI IL SECONDO NUMERO: "));

   if (a > b) {
   console.log()
    }

    }
```

obv it doesn't work because A and B were declared first at the beginning, but I don't know how to give them a value...
thank you guys, I'm waiting for updates.."

Comment: It's really unclear what the problem is here, since you appear to be giving `a` and `b` values just fine. (It's weird that you are declaring them as arguments, but that shouldn't stop it working).

Answer (score 1):

You have everything there, you just need to separate it so that the values from a and b are passed to your max function.

```js
function max(a, b) {
  if (a > b) {
    console.log(a + " > " + b)
  }
  else if(a == b){
    console.log(a + " = " + b)
  }
  else{
    console.log(b + " > " + a)
  }
}

a = Number(prompt("INSERISCI IL PRIMO NUMERO: "));
b = Number(prompt("INSERISCI IL SECONDO NUMERO: "));

max(a, b);
```

Comment: What if `a` and `b` are equal? ;-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat, I suppose I should have thought that one through! I have updated my answer accordingly.